# Set Bar Colours for ggplot geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I think I've looked through about 100 threads trying to find the answer to this.

Seems so simple but I just cannot get this right

Just wanting to creating a histogram of frequency counts for my demo column. It has 4 possible values and I want to give each one its own colour

I've defined a set of colours to apply, just whatever syntax I apply it just doesn't seem happy with the approach in the code

```
    p1_demo_col = c("#fef0d9", "#fdcc8a", "#fc8d59", "#d7301f")

    p1_demo  <- a3_pre %>% ggplot(aes(x = demo)) +
     labs(x = "Demo", y = 'Count', 
     title = "Histogram of Demo") +
     geom_bar(aes(fill = demo)) +
     theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
     scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,200))
```

Any guidance greatly appreciated

Thanks

Arden

Comment: We don't have `a3_pre`, perhaps you could demonstrate on an example data set like `mtcars`? Or share the output of `dput(a3_pre)` so we can recreate it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using mtcars and three categories. `scale_fill_manual` lets you specify the colors you want in order of the categories.

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(demo = as.character(cyl)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = demo, fill = demo)) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#fef0d9", "#fdcc8a", "#fc8d59"))
```

[image]